# How to upload image with preview in react js

Tags: reactjs

I have a reactjs application. I would like to know how to upload image with preview. Please advise.

Comment: Please review [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example of code attempt. Try to include specific details about what is or isn't working as expected, and what your expected result should be.

Answer (score 0):

you must read [this mdn document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL) about FileReader.

And then, based on your understand, you can apply like this.

```
export default () => {
    const [preview, setPreview] = useState(null);

    const fileHandler = evt => {
        const f = evt.target.files[0];

        if (f) {
            const reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = ({ target: { result } }) => {
                setPreview(result);
            };

            reader.readAsDataURL(f); // you can read image file as DataURL like this.
        } else {
            setPreview(null);
        }
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <input
               type="file"
               accept="image/*"
               onChange={fileHandler}
            />
            { preview && <img src={preview} /> }
        </div>);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following illustrated code example is a part of [my project](https://github.com/MeRahulAhire/cfm-dev/blob/master/src/form/register/ProfileDetail.js).
As long as if you aren't following strict react pratices then this should work really well. You can change the styling as per your needs.

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
class App extends Component {
    render() {
        const imageHandler = () => {
            const inpFile = document.getElementById('inpFile');
            const previewContainer = document.getElementById('imagePreview');
            const previewImage = previewContainer.querySelector('.image-preview__image');
            const previewDefaultText = previewContainer.querySelector('.image-preview__default-text');

            inpFile.addEventListener('change', function() {
                const file = this.files[0];

                if (file) {
                    const reader = new FileReader();

                    previewDefaultText.style.display = 'none';
                    previewImage.style.display = 'block';

                    reader.addEventListener('load', function() {
                        previewImage.setAttribute('src', this.result);
                    });

                    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
                } else {
                    previewDefaultText.style.display = null;
                    previewImage.style.display = null;
                    previewImage.setAttribute('src', '');
                }
            });
        };

        return (
            <div>
                <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet" />

                <div className="login">
                    <div className="reg-container">
                        <div className="profile-pic">
                            Add your Profile Picture:
                            <div className="add-picture">
                                <div className="image-preview" id="imagePreview">
                                    <div className="card-image" />
                                    <img alt="" className="image-preview__image" />
                                    <span className="image-preview__default-text" />
                                </div>

                                <input
                                    onClick={imageHandler}
                                    type="file"
                                    name="inpFile"
                                    id="inpFile"
                                    accept="image/*"
                                />
                                <div className="label-holder">
                                    <label className="image-upload" for="inpFile">
                                        <i className="material-icons">add_photo_alternate</i>
                                        Choose your Photo
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

and obviously the styling file `App.css`

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato|Varela+Round&display=swap');

*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.profile-pic {
    font-family: 'Varela Round', sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 1rem;
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
}
/* ============================== */
.add-picture{
    margin: auto;
    font-size: 1rem;
    display: flex;
    text-align: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;

}
.image-preview{
    width: 120px; 
    min-height: 150px; 
    border: 5px solid black; 
    margin-top: 15px; 
    border-radius: 15px;
    display: flex; 
    align-items: center; 
    justify-content: center; 
    font-weight: bold; 
    color: #000; 
    outline: none;
    z-index: ;
} 

    .image-preview__image{ 
    display: none; 
    width: 100%; 
    height: 150px;
    display:block;
    object-fit: cover;
    z-index: -11;
    }

    span{

        /* background-image: url("../blank_user.webp");  */
        width: 120px;
        height: 150px;
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center;
        z-index: -9;
        position: absolute;
        border-radius: 15px;
        outline: none;
    }
    #inpFile[type="file"]{
     display:none;
     margin-top: 20px;
    }
    .label-holder{
        width: 200px;
        height: 50px;
        margin-top: 1rem;

    }
    .image-upload{
        color: white;
        background-color: black;
        border: 1px solid #000;
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 6px 12px;
        cursor: pointer;
        font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        border-radius: 50px;
    }

.description {
    font-family: 'Varela Round', sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 1rem;
    padding-top: 0;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.description textarea{
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1rem;
    background: none;
    width: 350px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-radius: 10px;
    outline: none;
    text-align: center;

}

@media screen and (max-width:550px){
    .description textarea{
        width: 260px;
    }
}
```

Consider watching this [Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VElnT8EoEEM) and other online article

you can also add the state management to the `<input/>`